# setPreferredSize e setSize não funcionam

Tags: java, button

Usei o `setPreferredSize` e o `setSize` no botão `color1` porem nenhum surtiu efeito na aplicação, ele continua usando toda a aplicação.

```
public static void janelaPrincipal()
{
    //FRAME
    JFrame janela = new JFrame();
    janela.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    janela.pack();
    janela.setResizable(false);
    janela.setVisible(true);
    janela.setSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));   
    janela.setLocation((SCREEN.width / 2) - (WIDTH / 2), (SCREEN.height / 2) - (HEIGHT / 2));

    //PAINEIS
    JPanel fundo = new JPanel();

    fundo.setSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
    fundo.setBackground(background);

    //BOTOES
    JButton color1 = new JButton();

    color1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTHBUTTON, HEIGHTBUTTON));
    color1.setBackground(RED);

    //ADICIONAR NO FRAME
    janela.add(fundo);
    janela.add(color1);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por defeito, o JFrame usa o Layout BorderLayout, significa isto que, quando adicionas um JButton, como este é o único componente na frame, ele será redimensionado por forma a ocupar a janela inteira. Podes consultar este [exemplo](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) para teres uma melhor percepção do que se passa com o teu layout.

Se quiseres que o tamanho do botão seja exactamente aquele que defines com o SetPreferredSize() então deves alterar o layout do JFrame para algo diferente: FlowLayout ou GridLayout, por exemplo. Após isto podes definir o tamanho com o SetPreferredSize().

No teu exemplo o código ficaria assim:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class JanelaPrincipal {

    protected JFrame  janela = new JFrame("Teste");
    protected JButton color1 = new JButton("Exemplo");

    public static void main(String st[]) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                JanelaPrincipal j = new JanelaPrincipal();
                j.load();
            }
        });

    }
    public void load() {

        janela.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        janela.setSize(new Dimension(500, 500));   
        janela.setResizable(false);
        janela.setVisible(true);

        Container c = janela.getContentPane();
        c.setLayout(new FlowLayout()); //altera o layout para FlowLayout explicitamente

        color1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,50));//dimensoes do botão

        c.add(color1);
    }

}
```